# Rebuilding php array

Tags: php

I am trying to rebuild php array, which I can get with one query from database.
To build lists and add items I need the array to be grouped and rebuild.
From query I receive array like this:

```
    array (
    0 => 
    array (
    'item_id' => '1',
    'item_name' => 'aaa',
    'group_id' => '7',
    'group_name' => 'first'
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
    'item_id' => '2',
    'item_name' => 'bbb',
    'group_id' => '7',
    'group_name' => 'first'
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
    'item_id' => '3',
    'item_name' => 'ccc',
    'group_id' => '9',
    'group_name' => 'second'
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
    'item_id' => '4',
    'item_name' => 'ddd',
    'group_id' => '9',
    'group_name' => 'second'
    )
    );
```

I need to rearrange this array to following, which I can use for js parsing:

```
    array(
    array ('group_id' => '7', 'group_name' => 'first', 'items' => array (
    0 => array (
    'item_id' => '1',
    'item_name' => 'aaa',
    ),
    1 => array (
    'item_id' => '2',
    'item_name' => 'bbb',
    )
    )
    ),
    array ('id' => '8', 'name' => 'second', 'items' => array (
    0 => 
    array (
    'item_id' => '3',
    'item_name' => 'ccc',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
    'item_id' => '4',
    'item_name' => 'ddd',
    )
    )
    )
    );
```

I have stuck with following code:

```
    function rebuild($groupby, $param, $data) {
    $newarray = array();
    foreach($data as $key => $val) {
        if(array_key_exists($groupby, $val)){
            $newarray[$val[$groupby]] = $val[$param];
            $newarray['items'][] = $val;    
        }else{
        $newarray[""][] = $val;
       }
    }
    return $newarray;
    }
    $show = rebuild('group_id', 'group_name', $data);
    echo "<pre>" . var_export($show, true) . "</pre>";
```

Any advise would appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always like to use the unique identifier (here, the group ID), as array *key* in the resulting array - that makes it easier to associate the right items to the right new entry, without having to “search” the new array for the entry with the matching identifier.

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($data as $item) {
  $newarray[$item['group_id']]['group_id'] = $item['group_id'];
  $newarray[$item['group_id']]['group_name'] = $item['group_name'];
  $newarray[$item['group_id']]['items'][] = [
    'item_id' => $item['item_id'],
    'item_name' => $item['item_name']
  ];
}
$newarray = array_values($newarray); // resets the array keys to a zero-based index
var_dump($newarray);
```

group_id and group_name get overwritten in the result array elements all the time - but since we access the correct entry *by* the group id already, that does not matter. They will always be “overwritten” with the values they already have, so that does no harm.

And item_id and item_name simply get added to the `items` *array* of the entry identified by the group id.

Comment: Works nicely. Thanks a lot!